# Issue with snapping of first and last item in recyclerview using LinearSnapHelper

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, kotlin, android-animation, horizontal-scrolling

I have `recyclerView` which can be scrolled in horizontal orientation. Each view will snap to the center of the display. To implement this I used LinearSnapHelper. This tool works just fine.

Problem is with **last** and **first** item in a recyclerview. These two are `not snapped to the center` as you scroll to the start. If you check recyclerview state at the beginning before scrolling happen, you can see that first item is in right position in a centre of the screen. I achieved this by adding my custom ItemOffsetDecoration. I've added extra padding for last and first view based on width of the display and view itself, so it will position it right in a middle.

Problem is, if you scroll the recyclerview and scroll it back to the start or the end, those views are not snapped to the middle. It looks like that LinearSnapHelper cannot detect them as snapped.

**RecyclerViewInit:**

```
timelineSnapHelper = LinearSnapHelper()
    timelineViewManager = LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false)
    timelineViewAdapter = TimelineListAdapter(timelineViewManager, timelineList, this)
    timelineOffsetDecoration = ItemOffsetDecoration(context!!, 32, 45)

    timelineRecyclerView = view.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.timeline_recycler_view).apply {
        layoutManager = timelineViewManager
        adapter = timelineViewAdapter
        addItemDecoration(timelineOffsetDecoration)
        setHasFixedSize(true)
    }

    timelineSnapHelper.attachToRecyclerView(timelineRecyclerView)

    timelineRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(object : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        override fun onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView: RecyclerView?, newState: Int) {
            if (newState == AbsListView.OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                val centerView = timelineSnapHelper.findSnapView(timelineRecyclerView.layoutManager)
                val anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.scale_timeline_start)
                centerView!!.startAnimation(anim)
                anim.fillAfter = true
                lastSnappedTime = centerView
            } else if (lastSnappedTime != null){
                lastSnappedTime = null
            }

            if(newState == AbsListView.OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_TOUCH_SCROLL && lastSnappedTime != null){
                val anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.scale_timeline_end)
                lastSnappedTime!!.startAnimation(anim)
                anim.fillAfter = true
            }
        }
    })
```

**Custom ItemDecoration:**

```
class ItemOffsetDecoration(private val context: Context, private val edgePadding: Int, private var viewWidth: Int): RecyclerView.ItemDecoration() {


override fun getItemOffsets(outRect: Rect, view: View, parent: RecyclerView, state: RecyclerView.State?) {
    super.getItemOffsets(outRect, view, parent, state)

    val itemCount = state!!.itemCount


    val itemPosition = parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view)
    // no position, leave it alone
    if (itemPosition == RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
        return
    }

    val displayMetrics = context.resources.displayMetrics
    val displayWidth: Int = displayMetrics.widthPixels
    val viewPixelWidth: Int = (viewWidth * (displayMetrics.densityDpi / 160f)).toInt()
    val startEndPadding: Int = (displayWidth - viewPixelWidth) / 2

    // first item
    if (itemPosition == 0) {
        outRect.set(startEndPadding, edgePadding, edgePadding, edgePadding)
    }
    // last item
    else if (itemCount > 0 && itemPosition == itemCount - 1) {
        outRect.set(edgePadding, edgePadding, startEndPadding, edgePadding)
    }
    // every other item
    else {
        outRect.set(edgePadding, edgePadding, edgePadding, edgePadding)
    }
 }
}
```

Short preview of the issue in app(`I have to fix some animation bugs yet :D`):

[image]

Comment: When you say that the "LinearSnapHelper cannot detect them as snapped" do you mean that the text is not _precisely_ placed in the center? If so, they must just be a few pixels off because they look centered to me or do I misunderstand? I take it that you aren't talking about the lack of animation on the first and last item but the actual placement.

Comment: Correct and they are off. Because first and last item has that extra padding added to the view. And SnapHelper is calculating whole view as padding+view_width as width of the view. But I dont really know how to do it differently. If i change view padding it will malfunction SnapHelper snapping ability. But every single item has padding top/left/right/bottom 32dp set in ItemOffsetDecoration and other items are working fine. That extra padding_start for 1st item and padding_end for last item is an issue. Its sometimes over 200dp (calculated in ItemOffsetDecoration)

Comment: That's what I thought. See my answer for another way to approach this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RecyclerView SnapHelper fails to show first/last items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52688974/recyclerview-snaphelper-fails-to-show-first-last-items)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`LinearSnapHelper` includes the item decoration in the measurement of the associated view, so your first and last view are never really centered since the measured view size extends to the left or right of the `RecyclerView`.

You did not post your XML, so you might already do something like the following. The typical way to get start and end views centered correctly is to add padding to the `RecyclerView` and specify `android:clipToPadding="false"`. This is the same technique to move end views from FABs, etc.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:paddingStart="35dp"
    android:paddingEnd="35dp"/>
```

Here `35dp` would have to be adjusted for your app and layouts and you will not need the item decoration shifting the views is its only purpose.

Comment: There was an issue with my clipToPadding. It did not work properly because of the recyclerview parent layout. But now it works.

Comment: @martin1337 can you tell me what was the issue?

Comment: @martin1337 why mark this answer as correct if there's something more to it? My recyclerView has padding/clipToPadding set like above