# RecyclerView SnapHelper fails to show first/last items

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, kotlin

I have a `RecyclerView` which is attached to a `LinearSnapHelper` to snap to center item. When I scroll to the first or last items, these items are not fully visible anymore. This problem is shown in the following image. How to solve it?

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This issue happens when center of item which is next to the first/last is closer to the center of container. So, we should make some changes on snapping functionality to ignore this case. Since we need some fields in `LinearSnapHelper` class, we can copy its source code and make change on `findCenterView` method as following:

**MyLinearSnapHelper.kt**

```
/*
 * Copyright (C) 2016 The Android Open Source Project
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */
package com.aminography.view.component

import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import android.support.v7.widget.OrientationHelper
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
import android.support.v7.widget.SnapHelper
import android.view.View

/**
 * Implementation of the [SnapHelper] supporting snapping in either vertical or horizontal
 * orientation.
 *
 *
 * The implementation will snap the center of the target child view to the center of
 * the attached [RecyclerView]. If you intend to change this behavior then override
 * [SnapHelper.calculateDistanceToFinalSnap].
 */
class MyLinearSnapHelper : SnapHelper() {
    // Orientation helpers are lazily created per LayoutManager.
    private var mVerticalHelper: OrientationHelper? = null
    private var mHorizontalHelper: OrientationHelper? = null
    override fun calculateDistanceToFinalSnap(
            layoutManager: RecyclerView.LayoutManager, targetView: View): IntArray? {
        val out = IntArray(2)
        if (layoutManager.canScrollHorizontally()) {
            out[0] = distanceToCenter(layoutManager, targetView,
                    getHorizontalHelper(layoutManager))
        } else {
            out[0] = 0
        }
        if (layoutManager.canScrollVertically()) {
            out[1] = distanceToCenter(layoutManager, targetView,
                    getVerticalHelper(layoutManager))
        } else {
            out[1] = 0
        }
        return out
    }

    override fun findTargetSnapPosition(layoutManager: RecyclerView.LayoutManager, velocityX: Int,
                                        velocityY: Int): Int {
        if (layoutManager !is RecyclerView.SmoothScroller.ScrollVectorProvider) {
            return RecyclerView.NO_POSITION
        }
        val itemCount = layoutManager.itemCount
        if (itemCount == 0) {
            return RecyclerView.NO_POSITION
        }
        val currentView = findSnapView(layoutManager) ?: return RecyclerView.NO_POSITION
        val currentPosition = layoutManager.getPosition(currentView)
        if (currentPosition == RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
            return RecyclerView.NO_POSITION
        }
        val vectorProvider = layoutManager as RecyclerView.SmoothScroller.ScrollVectorProvider
        // deltaJumps sign comes from the velocity which may not match the order of children in
        // the LayoutManager. To overcome this, we ask for a vector from the LayoutManager to
        // get the direction.
        val vectorForEnd = vectorProvider.computeScrollVectorForPosition(itemCount - 1)
                ?: // cannot get a vector for the given position.
                return RecyclerView.NO_POSITION
        var vDeltaJump: Int
        var hDeltaJump: Int
        if (layoutManager.canScrollHorizontally()) {
            hDeltaJump = estimateNextPositionDiffForFling(layoutManager,
                    getHorizontalHelper(layoutManager), velocityX, 0)
            if (vectorForEnd.x < 0) {
                hDeltaJump = -hDeltaJump
            }
        } else {
            hDeltaJump = 0
        }
        if (layoutManager.canScrollVertically()) {
            vDeltaJump = estimateNextPositionDiffForFling(layoutManager,
                    getVerticalHelper(layoutManager), 0, velocityY)
            if (vectorForEnd.y < 0) {
                vDeltaJump = -vDeltaJump
            }
        } else {
            vDeltaJump = 0
        }
        val deltaJump = if (layoutManager.canScrollVertically()) vDeltaJump else hDeltaJump
        if (deltaJump == 0) {
            return RecyclerView.NO_POSITION
        }
        var targetPos = currentPosition + deltaJump
        if (targetPos < 0) {
            targetPos = 0
        }
        if (targetPos >= itemCount) {
            targetPos = itemCount - 1
        }
        return targetPos
    }

    override fun findSnapView(layoutManager: RecyclerView.LayoutManager): View? {
        if (layoutManager.canScrollVertically()) {
            return findCenterView(layoutManager, getVerticalHelper(layoutManager))
        } else if (layoutManager.canScrollHorizontally()) {
            return findCenterView(layoutManager, getHorizontalHelper(layoutManager))
        }
        return null
    }

    private fun distanceToCenter(layoutManager: RecyclerView.LayoutManager,
                                 targetView: View, helper: OrientationHelper): Int {
        val childCenter = helper.getDecoratedStart(targetView) + helper.getDecoratedMeasurement(targetView) / 2
        val containerCenter: Int = if (layoutManager.clipToPadding) {
            helper.startAfterPadding + helper.totalSpace / 2
        } else {
            helper.end / 2
        }
        return childCenter - containerCenter
    }

    /**
     * Estimates a position to which SnapHelper will try to scroll to in response to a fling.
     *
     * @param layoutManager The [RecyclerView.LayoutManager] associated with the attached
     * [RecyclerView].
     * @param helper        The [OrientationHelper] that is created from the LayoutManager.
     * @param velocityX     The velocity on the x axis.
     * @param velocityY     The velocity on the y axis.
     *
     * @return The diff between the target scroll position and the current position.
     */
    private fun estimateNextPositionDiffForFling(layoutManager: RecyclerView.LayoutManager,
                                                 helper: OrientationHelper, velocityX: Int, velocityY: Int): Int {
        val distances = calculateScrollDistance(velocityX, velocityY)
        val distancePerChild = computeDistancePerChild(layoutManager, helper)
        if (distancePerChild <= 0) {
            return 0
        }
        val distance = if (Math.abs(distances[0]) > Math.abs(distances[1])) distances[0] else distances[1]
        return Math.round(distance / distancePerChild)
    }

    /**
     * Return the child view that is currently closest to the center of this parent.
     *
     * @param layoutManager The [RecyclerView.LayoutManager] associated with the attached
     * [RecyclerView].
     * @param helper The relevant [OrientationHelper] for the attached [RecyclerView].
     *
     * @return the child view that is currently closest to the center of this parent.
     */
    private fun findCenterView(layoutManager: RecyclerView.LayoutManager,
                               helper: OrientationHelper): View? {
        // ----- Added by aminography
        if (layoutManager is LinearLayoutManager) {
            if (layoutManager.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition() == 0) {
                return layoutManager.getChildAt(0)
            } else if (layoutManager.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition() == layoutManager.itemCount - 1) {
                return layoutManager.getChildAt(layoutManager.itemCount - 1)
            }
        }
        // -----

        val childCount = layoutManager.childCount
        if (childCount == 0) {
            return null
        }
        var closestChild: View? = null
        val center: Int = if (layoutManager.clipToPadding) {
            helper.startAfterPadding + helper.totalSpace / 2
        } else {
            helper.end / 2
        }
        var absClosest = Integer.MAX_VALUE
        for (i in 0 until childCount) {
            val child = layoutManager.getChildAt(i)
            val childCenter = helper.getDecoratedStart(child) + helper.getDecoratedMeasurement(child) / 2
            val absDistance = Math.abs(childCenter - center)
            /** if child center is closer than previous closest, set it as closest   */
            if (absDistance < absClosest) {
                absClosest = absDistance
                closestChild = child
            }
        }
        return closestChild
    }

    /**
     * Computes an average pixel value to pass a single child.
     *
     *
     * Returns a negative value if it cannot be calculated.
     *
     * @param layoutManager The [RecyclerView.LayoutManager] associated with the attached
     * [RecyclerView].
     * @param helper        The relevant [OrientationHelper] for the attached
     * [RecyclerView.LayoutManager].
     *
     * @return A float value that is the average number of pixels needed to scroll by one view in
     * the relevant direction.
     */
    private fun computeDistancePerChild(layoutManager: RecyclerView.LayoutManager,
                                        helper: OrientationHelper): Float {
        var minPosView: View? = null
        var maxPosView: View? = null
        var minPos = Integer.MAX_VALUE
        var maxPos = Integer.MIN_VALUE
        val childCount = layoutManager.childCount
        if (childCount == 0) {
            return INVALID_DISTANCE
        }
        for (i in 0 until childCount) {
            val child = layoutManager.getChildAt(i)
            val pos = layoutManager.getPosition(child!!)
            if (pos == RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                continue
            }
            if (pos < minPos) {
                minPos = pos
                minPosView = child
            }
            if (pos > maxPos) {
                maxPos = pos
                maxPosView = child
            }
        }
        if (minPosView == null || maxPosView == null) {
            return INVALID_DISTANCE
        }
        val start = Math.min(helper.getDecoratedStart(minPosView),
                helper.getDecoratedStart(maxPosView))
        val end = Math.max(helper.getDecoratedEnd(minPosView),
                helper.getDecoratedEnd(maxPosView))
        val distance = end - start
        return if (distance == 0) {
            INVALID_DISTANCE
        } else 1f * distance / (maxPos - minPos + 1)
    }

    private fun getVerticalHelper(layoutManager: RecyclerView.LayoutManager): OrientationHelper {
        if (mVerticalHelper == null || mVerticalHelper!!.layoutManager !== layoutManager) {
            mVerticalHelper = OrientationHelper.createVerticalHelper(layoutManager)
        }
        return mVerticalHelper!!
    }

    private fun getHorizontalHelper(
            layoutManager: RecyclerView.LayoutManager): OrientationHelper {
        if (mHorizontalHelper == null || mHorizontalHelper!!.layoutManager !== layoutManager) {
            mHorizontalHelper = OrientationHelper.createHorizontalHelper(layoutManager)
        }
        return mHorizontalHelper!!
    }

    companion object {
        private const val INVALID_DISTANCE = 1f
    }

}
```

Answer (score 13):

A late answer simply written in Java code:

Create `CustomSnapHelper` class:

```
 public class CustomSnapHelper extends LinearSnapHelper {
        @Override
        public View findSnapView(RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager) {
            if(layoutManager instanceof LinearLayoutManager){
                LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = (LinearLayoutManager) layoutManager;
                if(needToDoSnap(linearLayoutManager)==false){
                    return null;
                }
            }
            return super.findSnapView(layoutManager);
        }
        public boolean needToDoSnap(LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager){
            return linearLayoutManager.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition()!=0&&linearLayoutManager.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition()!=linearLayoutManager.getItemCount()-1;
        }
    }
```

Attach an object of `CustomSnapHelper` to the recycler view:

```
CustomSnapHelper mSnapHelper = new CustomSnapHelper();
mSnapHelper.attachToRecyclerView(mRecyclerView);
```

Comment: Thanks! I hope it will help someone  :)

Answer (score 2):

I tried to implement a simple solution. Basically I checked if the first/last items are completely visible. If so, we don't need to perform the snap. See the solution below:

```
class CarouselSnapHelper : LinearSnapHelper() {

    override fun findSnapView(layoutManager: RecyclerView.LayoutManager): View? {
        val linearLayoutManager = layoutManager as? LinearLayoutManager
            ?: return super.findSnapView(layoutManager)

        return linearLayoutManager
            .takeIf { isValidSnap(it) }
            ?.run { super.findSnapView(layoutManager) }
    }

    private fun isValidSnap(linearLayoutManager: LinearLayoutManager) =
        linearLayoutManager.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition() != 0 &&
            linearLayoutManager.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition() != linearLayoutManager.itemCount - 1
}
```

Comment: Sorry I can't check this answer at this time, but I hope this help another users :)

Answer (score -1):

I found a less invasive answer:

```
private class PagerSelectSnapHelper : LinearSnapHelper() {

    override fun findSnapView(layoutManager: RecyclerView.LayoutManager): View? {
        // Use existing LinearSnapHelper but override when the itemDecoration calculations are off
        val snapView = super.findSnapView(layoutManager)
        return if (!snapView.isViewInCenterOfParent(layoutManager.width)) {
            val endView = layoutManager.findViewByPosition(layoutManager.itemCount - 1)
            val startView = layoutManager.findViewByPosition(0)

            when {
                endView.isViewInCenterOfParent(layoutManager.width) -> endView
                startView.isViewInCenterOfParent(layoutManager.width) -> startView
                else -> snapView
            }
        } else {
            snapView
        }
    }

    private fun View?.isViewInCenterOfParent(parentWidth: Int): Boolean {
        if (this == null || width == 0) {
            return false
        }
        val parentCenter = parentWidth / 2
        return left < parentCenter && parentCenter < right
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it :)